# Google Maps API - return error if Lat/Lng incorrect

Tags: google-maps-markers

I have a Goggle Map displaying markers based on a list being pulled from a database via php. It all works OK but will display a blank grey map page if one of the lng/lats are incorrect.

eg: "510.51356, -0.7015494" rather than "53.8741174, -0.7015494"

I've tried:

`var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(510.51356, -0.7015494);`

`console.log(myLatlng);`

Thinking it would return an error but doesn't - it returns an object but no data - but this is the same whether the lng/lat is correct or not.

[image]

Is there a way I can stop GoogleMaps from trying to add markers with incorrect lng/lats?

Below is the full code I'm using:

````
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(510.51356,-0.7015494);
                
            var markerOptions = {
                map: map,
                position: myLatlng,
                title: “MY LOCATION TITLE”      
            };
            marker_3744 = createMarker_map(markerOptions);
            
            marker_3744.set("content", "<strong>MY LOCATION TITLE</strong><br /><strong>Full address in here”);
            
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker_3744, "click", function(event) {
                iw_map.setContent(this.get("content"));
                iw_map.open(map, this);
            
            });```
````

Comment: Sounds like you should check the lat/long you are receiving before consuming it. Just check that each is in the proper range of values before building your lat/long object.

Comment: Yes I think you are right - I just assumed the API would throw an error rather than fall over.

Comment: If you grab a debug tool and make the calls, do you get a 200 or 201 success message back from Google? Or do you get some sort of error message from them there? Not familiar enough with the Google maps API to tell you. I can tell you that doing the same thing using Bing Will indeed result in an exception message along with a 200 response